# Need to download Excelsheet in ADF using Apache POI

Tags: excel, download, apache-poi, oracle-adf

I am working with ADF. I have seen so many posts on downloading excelsheet using java and tried number of ways.

They suggest to use Servelet. But in my case, I am using ViewObjects and iterators in my managed bean. Workbook object (With all the data) will be formed in managed bean and I am able to save the file locally in my desktop, but on other desktop it's either not saving or saving and opening on my desktop.

I tried servelet:

```
                  FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) fc.getExternalContext().getResponse();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        response = (HttpServletResponse) fc.getExternalContext().getResponse();
      //  ADFUtils.setSessionAttribute("WorkSheetObj", workBook);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/excelsheetdownloadServlet");

  response = (HttpServletResponse) fc.getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=inline.xls"); 
        workBook.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

But here I have to get object of workBook which is formed in managed bean, so it is not working.

I directly tried to write a code in my managed bean.
But that also didnt help me. Please suggest me on downloading the excelsheet written from Apache POI on client machine.

Comment: What is your requirement over here..? Do you need to download the data in form of Excel sheet available in  VO on button click or something..?

Comment: I have already downloaded the data from the VO in excelsheet using Apache POI. On Workbook.write() it is getting saved in my pc. But suppose if some test the link, the file will not open in there pc. Either it is getting saved in mine or it is not getting saved at all.

Comment: I need to save the generated excelsheet in client location.

Comment: As I understand, The client who is browsing thru the application on click of the download button, it will save on the client's system.

Is your application running on your local system?

Comment: Actually I have ran the application. I have made my computer as server. After running the application, I removed 127.0.0.1 with my computer's IP address and gave the application link to Test users to run the application and check. So whenever they will click on the download button, It will be getting downloaded in my PC.

Comment: It should get downloaded in their pc.

Comment: First let me know if you can access the application url from other system..

Comment: Yes, I am able to access it

Comment: Then I don’t see any issue in downloading the file in other system.. Your code will run on the server i.e. your system and the content will be delivered on the other system thru browser. You can monitor the server log for details.

Comment: I have been using file download action listener for downloading files and it is working without any issues. Try to use that approach and write your workbook content to output stream and close all the stream properly .